# Xcode: Wait for a NSURLConnetcion to download content

Tags: iphone, xcode, multithreading, nsurlconnection

I am programming an iPhone app. Now i want to download the contents of a text file and display them in a view.

The problem is that the view loads faster than the `NSURLConnection` can download the data. Is there a way to wait for the download before displaying the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: response error: &error];`

A better solution would be to wait for the callback, and in the meantime show a spinner.